# NotifyOfPropertyChange does not refresh the data in the map

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I have a problem refreshing the data after changing the report selected from combobox. In the ViewModel itself, the data changes, but the view does not refresh. Advice what am I doing wrong? Or what should I improve?

At the start, the data loads well and the map is colored, the only problem is changing the report and thus the lack of map refresh.

This is what I have at xaml:

```
<UserControl x:Class="DB.UI.Dashboard.NFZ.Maps.Views.CountiesMapView"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:DB.UI.Dashboard.NFZ.Maps.Views"
         xmlns:syncfusion="clr-namespace:Syncfusion.UI.Xaml.Maps;assembly=Syncfusion.SfMaps.WPF"
         xmlns:materialDesign="http://materialdesigninxaml.net/winfx/xaml/themes"
         xmlns:viewModels="clr-namespace:DB.UI.Dashboard.NFZ.Maps.ViewModels"
         mc:Ignorable="d"
         d:DesignHeight="450"
         d:DesignWidth="800"
         Loaded="CountiesMapView_OnLoaded">
<UserControl.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <viewModels:CountiesMapViewModel x:Key="Vm"/>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</UserControl.Resources>
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="4*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid Grid.Column="0">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <materialDesign:Card Grid.Row="0"
                             Foreground="Black"
                             Padding="8"
                             Margin="10 10 10 10"
                             UniformCornerRadius="6"
                             Background="White">
            <Grid>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <TextBlock Grid.Row="0"
                           TextAlignment="Center"
                           HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                           Text="Wybierz Raport"
                           TextWrapping="Wrap"
                           FontWeight="Bold"
                           FontSize="18"
                           ToolTip="Podsumowanie danych dla Realizatora&#x0a; w wybranym okresie rozliczeniowym" />
                <Separator Grid.Row="1"
                           Margin="5 0 5 10" />
                <ComboBox Grid.Row="2"
                          x:Name="ReportTypeComboBox"
                          Margin="5 0 5 10"
                          ItemsSource="{Binding ReportType}"
                          SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedReport}"
                          MinWidth="100"
                          HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                          HorizontalContentAlignment="Center">
                </ComboBox>
            </Grid>
        </materialDesign:Card>
    </Grid>
    <Grid Grid.Column="1">
        <materialDesign:Card Foreground="Black"
                             Padding="8"
                             Margin="10 10 10 10"
                             UniformCornerRadius="6"
                             Background="White">
            <Grid>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <TextBlock Grid.Row="0"
                           TextAlignment="Center"
                           HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                           Text="Powiaty"
                           TextWrapping="Wrap"
                           FontWeight="Bold"
                           FontSize="18"
                           ToolTip="Podsumowanie danych dla Realizatora&#x0a; w wybranym okresie rozliczeniowym" />
                <Separator Grid.Row="1"
                           Margin="5 0 5 10" />
                <syncfusion:SfMap Grid.Row="2"
                                  x:Name="map"
                                  DataContext="{StaticResource Vm}">
                    <syncfusion:SfMap.Layers>
                        <syncfusion:ShapeFileLayer ItemsSource="{Binding Report}"
                                                   MapPopupVisibility="Visible"
                                                   ShapeIDPath="CountyId"
                                                   ShapeIDTableField="JPT_KOD_JE"
                                                   Uri="DB.UI.Resources.Maps.Powiaty.shp">
                            <syncfusion:ShapeFileLayer.ItemsTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <Grid Background="Transparent">
                                        <TextBlock Margin="5"
                                                   FontFamily="Segoe UI"
                                                   FontSize="12"
                                                   FontWeight="SemiBold"
                                                   Foreground="Black"
                                                   Opacity="1"
                                                   Text="{Binding Data.DataValue}" />
                                    </Grid>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </syncfusion:ShapeFileLayer.ItemsTemplate>
                            <syncfusion:ShapeFileLayer.ShapeSettings>
                                <syncfusion:ShapeSetting ShapeColorValuePath="DataValue"
                                                         ShapeStrokeThickness="1"
                                                         ShapeValuePath="DataValue">
                                    <syncfusion:ShapeSetting.FillSetting>
                                        <syncfusion:ShapeFillSetting AutoFillColors="False">
                                            <syncfusion:ShapeFillSetting.ColorMappings>
                                                <syncfusion:RangeColorMapping To="0"
                                                                              From="0"
                                                                              Color="Transparent" />
                                                <syncfusion:RangeColorMapping To="{Binding ToRange[0], Source={StaticResource Vm}}"
                                                                              From="{Binding FromRange[0], Source={StaticResource Vm}}"
                                                                              Color="#ddb0b7" />
                                                <syncfusion:RangeColorMapping To="{Binding ToRange[1], Source={StaticResource Vm}}"
                                                                              From="{Binding FromRange[1], Source={StaticResource Vm}}"
                                                                              Color="#deacb3" />
                                                <syncfusion:RangeColorMapping To="{Binding ToRange[2], Source={StaticResource Vm}}"
                                                                              From="{Binding FromRange[2], Source={StaticResource Vm}}"
                                                                              Color="#e0a7af" />
                                                <syncfusion:RangeColorMapping To="{Binding ToRange[3], Source={StaticResource Vm}}"
                                                                              From="{Binding FromRange[3], Source={StaticResource Vm}}"
                                                                              Color="#e1a3ac" />
                                                <syncfusion:RangeColorMapping To="{Binding ToRange[4], Source={StaticResource Vm}}"
                                                                              From="{Binding FromRange[4], Source={StaticResource Vm}}"
                                                                              Color="#e29fa8" />
                                                <syncfusion:RangeColorMapping To="{Binding ToRange[5], Source={StaticResource Vm}}"
                                                                              From="{Binding FromRange[5], Source={StaticResource Vm}}"
                                                                              Color="#e49aa3" />
                                                <syncfusion:RangeColorMapping To="{Binding ToRange[6], Source={StaticResource Vm}}"
                                                                              From="{Binding FromRange[6], Source={StaticResource Vm}}"
                                                                              Color="#e5969f" />
                                                <syncfusion:RangeColorMapping To="{Binding ToRange[7], Source={StaticResource Vm}}"
                                                                              From="{Binding FromRange[7], Source={StaticResource Vm}}"
                                                                              Color="#e6929b" />
                                                <syncfusion:RangeColorMapping To="{Binding ToRange[8], Source={StaticResource Vm}}"
                                                                              From="{Binding FromRange[8], Source={StaticResource Vm}}"
                                                                              Color="#e68d97" />
                                                <syncfusion:RangeColorMapping To="{Binding ToRange[9], Source={StaticResource Vm}}"
                                                                              From="{Binding FromRange[9], Source={StaticResource Vm}}"
                                                                              Color="#e78992" />
                                                <syncfusion:RangeColorMapping To="{Binding ToRange[10], Source={StaticResource Vm}}"
                                                                              From="{Binding FromRange[10], Source={StaticResource Vm}}"
                                                                              Color="#e8848e" />
                                                <syncfusion:RangeColorMapping To="{Binding ToRange[11], Source={StaticResource Vm}}"
                                                                              From="{Binding FromRange[11], Source={StaticResource Vm}}"
                                                                              Color="#e88089" />
                                                <syncfusion:RangeColorMapping To="{Binding ToRange[12], Source={StaticResource Vm}}"
                                                                              From="{Binding FromRange[12], Source={StaticResource Vm}}"
                                                                              Color="#e97b84" />
                                                <syncfusion:RangeColorMapping To="{Binding ToRange[13], Source={StaticResource Vm}}"
                                                                              From="{Binding FromRange[13], Source={StaticResource Vm}}"
                                                                              Color="#e9767f" />
                                                <syncfusion:RangeColorMapping To="{Binding ToRange[14], Source={StaticResource Vm}}"
                                                                              From="{Binding FromRange[14], Source={StaticResource Vm}}"
                                                                              Color="#ea727b" />
                                                <syncfusion:RangeColorMapping To="{Binding ToRange[15], Source={StaticResource Vm}}"
                                                                              From="{Binding FromRange[15], Source={StaticResource Vm}}"
                                                                              Color="#ea6d76" />
                                                <syncfusion:RangeColorMapping To="{Binding ToRange[16], Source={StaticResource Vm}}"
                                                                              From="{Binding FromRange[16], Source={StaticResource Vm}}"
                                                                              Color="#ea6871" />
                                                <syncfusion:RangeColorMapping To="{Binding ToRange[17], Source={StaticResource Vm}}"
                                                                              From="{Binding FromRange[17], Source={StaticResource Vm}}"
                                                                              Color="#ea636b" />
                                                <syncfusion:RangeColorMapping To="{Binding ToRange[18], Source={StaticResource Vm}}"
                                                                              From="{Binding FromRange[18], Source={StaticResource Vm}}"
                                                                              Color="#ea5e66" />
                                                <syncfusion:RangeColorMapping To="{Binding ToRange[19], Source={StaticResource Vm}}"
                                                                              From="{Binding FromRange[19], Source={StaticResource Vm}}"
                                                                              Color="#e95961" />
                                                <syncfusion:RangeColorMapping To="{Binding ToRange[20], Source={StaticResource Vm}}"
                                                                              From="{Binding FromRange[20], Source={StaticResource Vm}}"
                                                                              Color="#e9535c" />
                                                <syncfusion:RangeColorMapping To="{Binding ToRange[21], Source={StaticResource Vm}}"
                                                                              From="{Binding FromRange[21], Source={StaticResource Vm}}"
                                                                              Color="#e94e56" />
                                                <syncfusion:RangeColorMapping To="{Binding ToRange[22], Source={StaticResource Vm}}"
                                                                              From="{Binding FromRange[22], Source={StaticResource Vm}}"
                                                                              Color="#e84851" />
                                                <syncfusion:RangeColorMapping To="{Binding ToRange[23], Source={StaticResource Vm}}"
                                                                              From="{Binding FromRange[23], Source={StaticResource Vm}}"
                                                                              Color="#e7434c" />
                                                <syncfusion:RangeColorMapping To="{Binding ToRange[24], Source={StaticResource Vm}}"
                                                                              From="{Binding FromRange[24], Source={StaticResource Vm}}"
                                                                              Color="#e73c46" />
                                                <syncfusion:RangeColorMapping To="{Binding ToRange[25], Source={StaticResource Vm}}"
                                                                              From="{Binding FromRange[25], Source={StaticResource Vm}}"
                                                                              Color="#e63640" />
                                                <syncfusion:RangeColorMapping To="{Binding ToRange[26], Source={StaticResource Vm}}"
                                                                              From="{Binding FromRange[26], Source={StaticResource Vm}}"
                                                                              Color="#e52f3b" />
                                                <syncfusion:RangeColorMapping To="{Binding ToRange[27], Source={StaticResource Vm}}"
                                                                              From="{Binding FromRange[27], Source={StaticResource Vm}}"
                                                                              Color="#e42735" />
                                                <syncfusion:RangeColorMapping To="{Binding ToRange[28], Source={StaticResource Vm}}"
                                                                              From="{Binding FromRange[28], Source={StaticResource Vm}}"
                                                                              Color="#e21d2f" />
                                                <syncfusion:RangeColorMapping To="{Binding ToRange[29], Source={StaticResource Vm}}"
                                                                              From="{Binding FromRange[29], Source={StaticResource Vm}}"
                                                                              Color="#e11029" />
                                            </syncfusion:ShapeFillSetting.ColorMappings>
                                        </syncfusion:ShapeFillSetting>
                                    </syncfusion:ShapeSetting.FillSetting>
                                </syncfusion:ShapeSetting>
                            </syncfusion:ShapeFileLayer.ShapeSettings>
                            <syncfusion:ShapeFileLayer.PopupCustomTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <Border>
                                        <Grid Width="250">
                                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                                <RowDefinition />
                                                <RowDefinition />
                                                <RowDefinition />
                                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                <ColumnDefinition />
                                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                            <Border VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                                    Padding="10,5,0,0"
                                                    Height="30"
                                                    Background="#FF4B4A4A"
                                                    Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
                                                <TextBlock Foreground="White"
                                                           FontFamily="Segoe UI"
                                                           FontSize="14"
                                                           Text="{Binding CountyName}" />
                                            </Border>
                                            <Border Padding="3,10,3,3"
                                                    Background="White"
                                                    Grid.Row="1"
                                                    Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
                                                <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                                            VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                                            Height="35"
                                                            Background="White"
                                                            Orientation="Horizontal">
                                                    <TextBlock Foreground="Black"
                                                               FontFamily="Segoe UI"
                                                               FontSize="16"
                                                               Text="{Binding TooltipDataValue}" />
                                                </StackPanel>
                                            </Border>
                                            <Border HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                                    Grid.Row="2">
                                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                                    <ItemsControl Background="White"
                                                                  ItemsSource="{Binding DataValue}"
                                                                  DisplayMemberPath="CountyName" />
                                                    <ItemsControl  Background="White"
                                                                   ItemsSource="{Binding DataValue}"
                                                                   DisplayMemberPath="DataValue" />
                                                </StackPanel>
                                            </Border>
                                        </Grid>
                                    </Border>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </syncfusion:ShapeFileLayer.PopupCustomTemplate>
                        </syncfusion:ShapeFileLayer>
                    </syncfusion:SfMap.Layers>
                </syncfusion:SfMap>
            </Grid>
        </materialDesign:Card>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

and this is in ViewModel

```
public class CountiesMapViewModel : Screen
{
    private CountiesDataProvider _countiesDataProvider = new CountiesDataProvider();
    private MapReportType _mapDataType = new MapReportType();

    private ObservableCollection<MapData> _report;

    public ObservableCollection<MapData> Report
    {
        get { return _report; }
        set 
        { 
            _report = value; 
            NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => Report);
        }
    }
    private IEnumerable<Counties> _counties;
    public IEnumerable<Counties> Counties
    {
        get { return _counties; }
        set
        {
            _counties = value;
            NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => Counties);
        }
    }

    private ObservableCollection<int> _fromRange;

    public ObservableCollection<int> FromRange
    {
        get { return _fromRange; }
        set
        {
            _fromRange = value;
            NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => FromRange);
        }
    }

    private ObservableCollection<int> _toRange;

    public ObservableCollection<int> ToRange
    {
        get { return _toRange; }
        set
        {
            _toRange = value;
            NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => ToRange);
        }
    }

    public CountiesMapViewModel()
    {
        _counties = _countiesDataProvider.GetCounties;
        Report = new ObservableCollection<MapData>(PrepareReportData(_counties));
        PrepareDataRanges(Report.Max(rp => rp.DataValue));
    }

    public void PrepareDataRanges(decimal maxValue)
    {
        var fromList = new List<int>();
        var toList = new List<int>();

        var range = Convert.ToInt32(Math.Round(maxValue / 30));
        int lastTo = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++)
        {
            var from = lastTo;
            var to = lastTo + range;
            lastTo = to + 1;
            fromList.Add(from);
            toList.Add(to);
        }
        FromRange = new ObservableCollection<int>(fromList);
        ToRange = new ObservableCollection<int>(toList);
    }
    private ObservableCollection<MapData> PrepareReportData(IEnumerable<Counties> counties)
    {
        ObservableCollection<MapData> prepareReportData = new ObservableCollection<MapData>();
        switch (SelectedReport)
        {
            case "Liczba Świadczeń":
                foreach (var row in counties)
                {
                    prepareReportData.Add(new MapData()
                    {
                        CountyId = row.CountyId,
                        CountyName = row.County,
                        DataValue = row.NumberOfMedicals,
                        TooltipDataValue = $"Liczba świadczeń: {row.NumberOfMedicals}"
                    });
                }
                break;
            case "Liczba Pacjentów":
                foreach (var row in counties)
                {
                    prepareReportData.Add(new MapData()
                    {
                        CountyId = row.CountyId,
                        CountyName = row.County,
                        DataValue = row.NumberOfPatients,
                        TooltipDataValue = $"Liczba Pacjentów: {row.NumberOfPatients}"
                    });
                }
                break;
            case "Wartość Zrealizowanych Świadczeń":
                foreach (var row in counties)
                {
                    prepareReportData.Add(new MapData()
                    {
                        CountyId = row.CountyId,
                        CountyName = row.County,
                        DataValue = row.Execution,
                        TooltipDataValue = $"Wartość zrealizowanych świadczeń: {row.Execution:C}"
                    });
                }
                break;
            case "Liczba Zrealizowanych Punktów":
                foreach (var row in counties)
                {
                    prepareReportData.Add(new MapData()
                    {
                        CountyId = row.CountyId,
                        CountyName = row.County,
                        DataValue = row.Points,
                        TooltipDataValue = $"Zrealizowane punkty: {row.Points:N2}"
                    });
                }
                break;
        }
        return prepareReportData;
    }
    private List<string> _reportType;

    public List<string> ReportType
    {
        get { return _mapDataType.ReportType; }

        set
        {
            _reportType = value;
            NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => ReportType);
            NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => Report);
        }
    }

    private string _selectedReport = "Liczba Świadczeń";

    public string SelectedReport
    {
        get { return _selectedReport; }
        set
        {
            _selectedReport = value;
            NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => SelectedReport);

            Report = new ObservableCollection<MapData>(PrepareReportData(_counties));
            PrepareDataRanges(Report.Max(rp => rp.DataValue));
            NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => Report);
        }
    }
}
public class MapData
{
    public int CountyId { get; set; }
    public string CountyName { get; set; }
    public decimal DataValue { get; set; }
    public string TooltipDataValue { get; set; }
}
```

I'm using CaliburnMicro and syncfusion for Map.

Answer (score 1):

A couple of things

1. The combobox is bound to nothing, so when a new value selected for the combobx, the code in the setter of `SelectedReport` is not executed

This is because you are setting the DataContext for the Map control only, so let's change the way view-viewmodel linkup

2. Replace

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <local:CountiesMapViewModel x:Key="Vm" />
    </ResourceDictionary>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

With

```
<UserControl.DataContext>
    <local:CountiesMapViewModel/>
</UserControl.DataContext>
```

Therefore, `CountiesMapViewModel` will be the DataContext for all of the UserControl.

Now, Remove all the occurrences of `DataContext="{StaticResource Vm}"` And `, Source={StaticResource Vm}` in '.xaml', no need for these at all (the second one is not even needed in your old code)

Give it a try..

Comment: I did according to the proposed solution. Now the data is changing on the map but has stopped colorizing. Neither at startup nor after the change to combobox. I tried to add DataContext = "{StaticResource Vm}" to Combobox and now both colors and data on the map change but: on startup the map loads 3-4 seconds, after switching to combobox two minutes ...

Comment: It's hard to tell, try to remove the `NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => Report);` in the setter of `SelectedReport`, you are notifying the UI twice in there, because in that setter you are assigning a new value to `Report`, and in the Report's setter there will be another `NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => Report);` call, especially that `Report` is an ObservableCollection.

Comment: I deleted `NotifyOfPropertyChange (() => Report);` from `public string SelectedReport`.  Unfortunately, it does not speed up the operation after changing the selected report from combobox :( I don't know what to do anymore. After starting it loads 4 seconds, I change the report ... two minutes ... drama @MuhammadSulaiman

Comment: Unfortunately, the snippets in your post are not enough to replicate the issue on my side, If you can make a small sample app and share it to make it easier to help (maybe in a separate post as this post was about a binding issue and not about the delay in map's ui updating).

Comment: I created a small example without using CaliburnMicro. Due to the map which is 80mb, the file weighs a little despite being packed. I'm ashamed to admit it, but I don't know how to include it here. I can send it to you by WeTransfer ... or some other way. @MuhammadSulaiman

Comment: nevermind, muhammad.b.sulaiman001@gmail.com

Comment: I sent the file, thanks again for your help @MuhammadSulaiman :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247972/discussion-between-muhammad-sulaiman-and-pepe).